# ST_AsRaster for polygon

Tags: postgis, raster, postgis-raster, st

Having a hard time to get a raster from a polygon

```
ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-30 40, -20 30, -25 20, -23 10, -30 40))', 4326), 50),ARRAY['8BUI'],ARRAY[118]);
```

This line is giving me an error : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing pixel dimensions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_raster;

SELECT ST_AsRaster(
   ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-30 40, -20 30, -25 20, -23 10, -30 40))', 4326), 50),
   100,            -- width 
   100,            -- height
   ARRAY['8BUI'],  -- pixeltype
   ARRAY[118]      -- value
 ); -- using ST_AsRaster signature (geometry,int,int,text[],float[])
```

In this example you can use also the signature *(geometry,int,int,text,float)*.

Comment: Copy/pasting that in gives the same error as OP was having.... Even copy/pasting the examples from the docs does.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell check again, if fail again you must to chech version and installation.